# ASP.NET and jQuery - call from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, jquery

This is a problem i've tried so solve before but gived up.
Basicly i'm using ModalPopupExtenders (from AJAX.NET) to display Panels with a few content (text, controls, etc). And i'm calling it from  codebehind. And it works well.

But now i want to replace the ModalPopup with some jQuery dialog box. The problem is calling it from codebehind.
As far as i know, i have to register the jQuery libraries on RegisterStartup event, but i've tried it and call the jQuery from codebehind but with no sucess.

Can someone help me? I really want to replace the ModalPopup, they gives me to much trouble.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "registerDialog",
        "$(function() { $('#dialog').dialog({autoOpen:false, show:'blind'}); });", true);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "openDialog",
        "$('#dialog').dialog('open');", true);
}
```

Is this the correct way? I've to register it first to stay hidden. 
Thanksю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a ScriptManager, use [`RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx), like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "modalscript",
    "$(function() { $('#dialog').dialog(); });", true);
```

If you're *not* using a ScriptManager/UpdatePanels, use [the equivalent `ClientScriptManager` version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx).

It's important to remember to wrap your code in a `document.ready` handler (IE has the most issues without it), so your elements (in my example, `id="dialog"`) are in the DOM and ready.

Comment: Thank you Nick.
When you say to wrap my code in a document.ready, in the sample i've showed bellow i did all from ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript 
Is there anything i should change? I've though in write the registerDialog on document.ready, but i don't know if it's the same.

Comment: @Guilherme - Change the `this` (first argument) to the UpdatePanel you're in if that's the case, also you're not using the `$(function() { });` wrapper in your RegisterStartupScript call, make sure to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually call jQuery from code behind, you just write some extra javascript code that's run on page load (after the PostBack).

In this start up code you make the jQuery calls.