# Add an OK and Cancel Button in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, alert

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.abc').click(function () {
            var status = $("#<%=ddlstatus.ClientID%>").val;
            if (status == "Prepared") {
                var _Action = confirm('Do you really want to cancel this payment ? All pending money will be available in the retention account of the contractor ');
                if (_Action) {
                    $.blockUI({ css: {
                        border: 'none',
                        padding: '15px',
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                        opacity: .5,
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }


            }

        });
    });
```

I get the OK button when I run this javascript but I want to add a cancel button as well.  Plus i am calling this from c# code behind

Comment: "but I want to add a cancel button as well"? Doesn't the confirm give you a cancel button?

Comment: nope i am not getting a cancel button

Comment: What other button are you getting?

Comment: var status = $("#<%=ddlstatus.ClientID%>").val; is it a typo or you missed .val();

Comment: You tagged this question with `alert`, but your code says `confirm`. Which are you using? The default/only options for `confirm` are "OK" and "Cancel" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. The JS `confirm()` function should produce a popup with both an OK button and a Cancel button. If you're only getting an OK button, that's an `alert()`, not a `confirm()`. Are you sure your JS looks like what you posted? Is it at all possible that you have duplicate code elsewhere that's executing instead of this, or that you changed it from `alert` to `confirm` and the page is cached? Try changing the message and see if you see the change when you execute it.

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "",
"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Do you really want to cancel this payment ? All pending money will be available in the retention account of the contractor');</script>"); i call this function from codebehind but it odes not show a cancel button

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/):

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Do you really want to cancel this payment? All pending money will be available in the retention account of the contractor. 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });
  });

  $(".abc").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
    var status = $("#<%=ddlstatus.ClientID%>").val();

    $("#dialog").dialog({
      buttons : {
        "Ok" : function() {              
         if (status == "Prepared") {
            $.blockUI({ css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    padding: '15px',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                    opacity: .5,
                    color: '#fff'
                    }
                }); 
          }
          window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
</script>
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/rCVrc/

***EDIT***:

Quoting Nick's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734326/122005), you can use the [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx) method, like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "modalscript",
    "$(function() { $('#dialog').dialog({
      buttons : {
        'Ok' : function() {              
         if (status == 'Prepared') {
            $.blockUI({ css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    padding: '15px',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                    opacity: .5,
                    color: '#fff'
                    }
                }); 
          }
          window.location.href = targetUrl;
        },
        'Cancel' : function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    }); });", true);
```

"If you're not using a ScriptManager/UpdatePanels, use the equivalent [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) version.

It's important to remember to wrap your code in a document.ready handler (IE has the most issues without it), so your elements (in my example, `id="dialog"`) are in the DOM and ready."

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "",
"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Do you really want to cancel this payment ? All pending money will be available in the retention account of the contractor');</script>");

Comment: i am calling this from code behind but it only displays an Ok button

Comment: Please see my edit for an update on calling the script from code behind. This is untested code, bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but does using `window.confirm()` give any improvement over `confirm()` ?

Answer (score 0):

`confirm()` should do the trick. Check this link. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

Comment: I said the same thing at first...even posted the same link. But then looked at the OP's code and saw that he is already claiming to be using `confirm`.